# Unable to view the data fetched from mysql in angularJs

Tags: mysql, angularjs

I am completely new to angularJs. I want to fetch the form data submitted to mysql database using php  and then display it on the ng-view.

Below is my code:

viewevent.js

```
eventsApp.factory('viewEvent',function($http,$log) 
   { return {  
        getEvent: function (successcb){
                     $http({method:'GET',
                           url:"http://localhost/apidocs/display.php"})
                     .success(function (data,headers,status,config){

                             successcb(data);

                        }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
                               $log.warn(data,status,header,config);
                        });
            }
           };
   });
```

viewCtrl.js

```
eventsApp.controller('viewCtrl',function viewCtrl($scope,viewEvent)
{
    viewEvent.getEvent(function(event){

           $scope.Events= event;


        });
});
```

And 
 ViewEvent.html

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="box-table-b" >
   <tr>
      <th> Name</th>
      <th> Address</th>
   </tr>
    </table>
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat = "Evnt in Events track by $index">{{Evnt.name}} <br/>                                               

           {{Evnt.address}}
        </li>
   </ul>



 </div>
```

Here's the php file I am using:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","eventsapp") ;
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
   echo 'Connected successfully'; 

 //select
$query = "SELECT * FROM event"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query); 
if (!mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM event")) {  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));    

  }

   $arr = array();
   $arr2 = array();

    //now we turn the results into an array and loop through them. 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

      $name = $row['name']; 
      $address = $row['address']; 
      $arr = array(
                  "name"=>$name,
                  "address"=>$address );

      array_push($arr2, $arr);



    } 
    echo json_encode($arr2);
 ?>
```

There is no error in my console.I am getting only bullets on the screen as my output.
Please guide!..Thankyou in advance for your suggestions..

Comment: What happens if you put a console log inside the callback function? the one with the assignment.

Comment: place console.log(data); in your callback and lets inspect the content

Comment: I cheked the content.. Wen i run my php file it shows me the json array of all the rows that are in the database..

Comment: but wen i view my ViewEvent.html file in browser it shows nothing except the bullets..!:(